# Vedic schools like Charvaka

Tags: atheism, vedic, charvaka

Were there any materialistic and overly skeptical schools of Vedic thought that are well-Vedic and got their inspiration from the Vedas? If not can some verses in Vedas support such materialistic philosophies? Please provide scriptural references thanks! :)

Comment: Charvaka was NOT a vedic school. It was a school that only accepted direct perception as the mode of its argument. Shankhya was the closest, they accepted direct perception as well as inference.

Comment: @User29449 schools LIKE and not is. From what I heard Nyaya had close connections with Ajana a Nastika school.

Comment: Shankhya is the closest to charvaka that accepts soul.

Comment: @User29449  okay! :)